# What's the real purpose of `ignore` function in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

There is an `ignore` function in OCaml.

```
val ignore : 'a -> unit
```

> Discard the value of its argument and return (). For instance,
>   ignore(f x) discards the result of the side-effecting function f. It
>   is equivalent to f x; (), except that the latter may generate a
>   compiler warning; writing ignore(f x) instead avoids the warning.

I know what this function will do, but don't get the point of using it.

Anyone can explain or give an example for when we *have to* use it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You basically answered your own question. You don't ever have to use it. The point is precisely to avoid the warning. If you write `f x; ()`, the compiler assumes you probably did something wrong. Probably you thought `f x` returns unit because you rarely want to ignore non-unit values.

However, sometimes that's not true, and you really want to ignore even non-unit values. Writing `ignore (f x)` documents the fact that you know `f x` returns something, but you are deliberately ignoring it.

Note that in real code `f x` might be something more complex, so the chances of you being wrong about the return type of `f x` are reasonably high. One example is partial application. Consider `f : int -> int -> unit`. You might accidentally write `f 1`, forgetting the second argument, and the warning will help you. Another example is if you do `open Async`, then many functions from the Standard Library change from returning unit to returning `unit Deferred.t`. Especially when first starting to use Async, it is quite likely that you'll accidentally think the semicolon operator is appropriate in places that you really need to use monadic bind.

Comment: I just think it twisted the logic a bit. say, if I understand writing `f x` before `unit` makes no sense, then I won't do it anyway; if I don't understand that, then I may write `f x` before `()` and I won't be able to think about `ignore` and use it as if I want to use `ignore` here then it is a contradiction to `i don't understand that fact` in the first place

Comment: I've added some examples that I hope will help.

Comment: is it the same as writing `let _ = f x in ()` ?

Comment: Yes, technically that's the same.

Answer (score 3):

As a complement to Ashish Agarwal's answer (because judging from your comment you don't seem very convinced) :

Imagine that I have a function that has side effects, and returns a value indicating something about the computation. Then, if I'm interested in how the computation went, I will need its return value. However, if I don't care about this and simply want the side effects to take place, I would use `ignore`.

Dumb example : let's say you have a function which sorts an array and returns `Was_already_sorted` or `Was_not_sorted` depending on the initial state of the array. Then if for some reason I'm interested in knowing how often my array was sorted, I might need the return value of this function. If not, I will ignore it.

I agree that this is a dumb example. And probably that in many cases there would be better ways to deal with the problem than using ignore (I've just noticed that I never use `ignore`). If you're really passionate about this, you could try to find examples of use of this function in real-life code (maybe in the source-code of software such as Unison?).

Also, note that you can use `let _ = f x` to the same end.